# persist image or video into voldemort

Tags: web-services, persistence

I am working on my web service, and required to persist some image (jpg whatever) and video(wmv) into memmory. Just want to use single_node_cluster to feel voldemort.

Can anybody give me a hint of the configuration and sample code of voldemort? I mean how to configure the value type in stores.xml? protobuf? java-serialization?

Any sample or link would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

sample code is [here](http://project-voldemort.com/quickstart.php). The same code is also in SAMPLE folder of voldemort installation.

Regarding image store in voldemort, you need to encode the image using `base64encoding` and then save the text generated in to the value.